# making the axis label clickable on chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, user-controls

So I have a gantt chart like app that I have made using C#, chart controls, and range bars and I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to make the Axis labels in to links.

I have seen a couple things online using the customize event to add a URL but that was in ASP.NET and I am using win forms.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HitTestResult` of the chart to figure out which element is clicked in the `MouseDown` event handler. You could then figure out which label it is, and open a webpage to the corresponding URL. Some example code from the chart samples project:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Mouse Down Event
    /// </summary>
    private void Chart1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call Hit Test Method
        HitTestResult result = Chart1.HitTest( e.X, e.Y );

        if( result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.AxisLabels && result.Axis == Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY )
        {
            StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();
            stripLine.IntervalOffset = ((CustomLabel) result.Object).FromPosition;
            stripLine.Interval = 200;
            stripLine.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 255,255, 255);
            stripLine.StripWidth = ((CustomLabel) result.Object).ToPosition - ((CustomLabel) result.Object).FromPosition;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.StripLines.Add( stripLine );
        }

    }
```

In the example, they create some `CustomLabel` objects:

```
        // Set Y axis custom labels
        axisY.CustomLabels.Add(0, 30,"Low");
        axisY.CustomLabels.Add(30, 70, "Medium");
        axisY.CustomLabels.Add(70,100,"High");
```

Not sure if it would work with the default labels or if you would need to do custom labels. Either way, you'd probably want to modify the font to make it look like a link (e.g., blue and underlined), and possibly change the font in the `MouseDown` handler (to e.g., purple). You could also use the `HitTestResult` in the `MouseMove` handler to change the cursor when over one of these fake link labels.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, I am displaying a large amount of information so every time I scroll the x,y position of the elements I would need to track would change. I ended up building something else, not as nice as it would have been but still works.

Comment: Post it as an answer so others can see it, too! Nothing wrong with answering your own question :)